# Rails 5 API doesn't have ActionDispatch::ParamsParser as a middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

Is it possible to add "ActionDispatch::ParamsParser" to Rails 5 API app as a custom middleware.

I have a custom middleware which updates the request object. when the request is forwarded to ActionDispatch::ParamsParser the parameter parsing fails.

Is it possible to add ActionDispatch::ParamsParser middleware before my custom middleware in rails 5 API app.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your middleware before the next one in line after `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser`, in this case `Rack::Head`.

You can get a list of available middleware using `bundle exec rake middleware`